# I can't see my vertex group in GeometryNodes modifier for Density

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was watching Blender Guru [Blender 3.0 Beginner Geometry Nodes Tutorial (Donut part 9)](https://youtu.be/4WAxMI1QJMQ) and I must select a vertex group for GeometryNodes modifier but I can't it. (I can explain this much with my English sorry for this)

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17gbWnwE9wZzkI5XQZ_LbGvyk_bWHPkna/view?usp=sharing)

[image] Mine

[image] Blender Guru's

[image] and my vertex group

Comment: please provide blend file. (if entering the name of your vertex group doesn't work)

Comment: I added it with Google Drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that You need to *re-enable* the Geometry node modifier in the view:

You will notice that in your version the box I have outlined in red is grayed out.  Toggle it on and the vertex group will appear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am grateful.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad I could help.  As a tip, when you watch his tutorials be alert for situations like that.  He did mention reenabling the modifier, but with almost no emphasis so it' was easy to miss.  A lot of tutorials are that way.

Comment: sounds like a bug to be reported on blender. view shouldn't affect what you can assign

Answer (score 0):

Although i didn't watch the tutorial, it will work with this node setup:

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.